# IIS, multiple CPU cores, application pools and worker processes - best configuration for a single site?

Tags: application-pools, iis

We use Kentico CMS and I've exchanged emails with them about a web garden deployment.

We have a single site running on a server with 8 cpu cores. In line with Kentico's advice, we have not altered the application pool web garden setting from the default i.e. it is set to a maximum number of worker processes of 1.

Our experience is that the site only uses one of the cpu cores - the others are idling. When I emailed them about this, their response was that the OS/IIS would handle this and use other cores as necessary even though the application pool only has a single worker process.

Now, I've a lot of respect for the guys at Kentico, but this doesn't seem right to me?

Surely, if we want to use all cores, we need to permit eight worker processes (and implement session state storage in SQL server)?

Many thanks

Tony

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it came up under related questions so I thought I'd chime in for those who might come across this at a later date. Scott Forsyth recommends against running web gardens because of the many challenges they raise.  [He has a video](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/06/13/why-you-shouldn-t-use-web-gardens-in-iis-week-24.aspx) on the subject which he intros with:

> This week’s lesson discusses why it’s rarely worth using Web Gardens and why using them is often detrimental to your server’s performance.

The biggest caveat is the implications for session state, but there are other challenges as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, in order to parallelize execution you need multiple worker processes and/or multiple application pools.

A bit of tuning will be required, anyway; you can't (usually) simply run as many WPs as CPU cores you have; especially if SQL Server is also running on the same server.

Comment: Massimo is right, going into a Web garden scenario will boost your application performance check this http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/performance_testing/boosting_performance_using_an_iis_web_garden, but you will need to keep an eye on this article as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx